# Reading Different csv's using springbatch

Tags: spring-batch

Hi I need help with reading different csv files using spring batch. Files are different types not able to get idea how to read. can somebody help me with this issue.

I'm using FlatFileItemReader to read one file. I need to read multiple files
example:

i need to read all files process and insert in to db.

Answer (score 0):

Files are of different types, so I would keep it simple use different items readers.

If those files can be processed independently, you can process them concurrently in different steps.